# Exist any hack for IE6 and IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

how can I hack CSS for IE6 and IE7 in same expression?? (if posible, of corse)

-edit-

i mean,

```
* html #div{   //hacks ie6}
*+html #div { //hacks ie7}
```

does a similar expresion hack both?

-edit2-

For example this inline code HTML

```
    <!--[if IE lte 7]>

<style type="text/css"> 

.contButton p a{ height:25px; width:auto; }
.contButton p a span{ height:25px;width:auto; }  
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

will only affect IE7 or lower, how can i select that in CSS ???

example:    `-*?? #div { //the CSS properties here will affect to IE6 and IE7 }`

Comment: What do you mean with *"in [the] same expression"*?

Comment: I edited, let me know if i expressed myself better (excuse my english)

Comment: mmmm.. that will only affect specified browser

Comment: edited my question, again; i am asking if -*?? exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use conditional style sheet includes like

   `<!--[if lte IE 7]>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="ie_fixes.css" />

   <![endif]-->`
2. or use the dirty solution using an asterisk (which makes your style sheets invalid in the eyes of validators)

   `.example_class {

       *background-color: #ffffff;

   }`

Comment: It works for browsers prior to IE8 only, but I'm not quite sure if IE 5.5 and lower is also affected.

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark my post as accepted answer to mark your issue as resolved. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) instead so your "hack" CSS is separate from your "modern browser" CSS:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css" src="ie7styles.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: this is not what i needed... i need to do this already in the stylesheet, if posible.